# Embedded Image Processing System that sends photos to Smartphone via Bluetooth

Tags: image-processing, hardware-implementation, photo

I would like to create an **embedded system** that takes a **Full HD** photo by pressing a button,**processes** and **compresses** it(for ex. to jpg) and then sends it via Bluetooth to the smartphone - where it's saved in the photo gallery.

I have already started to read "Digital Image processing" by Gonzalez, Woods, and I was thinking if, for my specific purpose, there isn't a better book with which to start.

I am interested to gain understanding about the **overall process** and the **number of components needed** for my task and **how would they connect with each other.**

Do you know any **reference material**(books/articles/experiments etc.) with which I could start?

I don't believe that I will find everything in one single book, so you can suggest different sources of information for each step needed in the process.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi William, and welcome to DSP.SE!  Your question is way too broad to be answered sensibly in the standard DSP.SE (or even most *.SE sites).  I'd suggest breaking it down and possibly splitting the resulting questions between this site and the EE.SE site (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Peter. I have tried to narrow down my question to  reference material, because that's what I'm looking for. Hope it's good enough. If not, then I'll give it another try!

Comment: Thanks, William! I'll reopen and let's see if we can get some answers for you.

Comment: You don't seem to have much experience in hardware design nor image processing, and you will discover that this cannot be learnt in a single day. Keep in mind that a smartphone IS an embedded system that takes a Full HD photo by pressing a button, processes and compresses it. It has generous resources for that purpose, a rich software environment, and costs peanuts.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your pursuit will be sorely disappointed by a DSP reference book. You'll want to explore the world of microcontrollers, bluetooth radios, and off the shelf image compression. Since you are likely not ordering 10,000 units, you'll want to check out Arduino and particular the various shields offered by Adafruit (or any one of the various Arduino or Raspberry Pi microcontroller distributors).

Answer (score 1):

This question is more of a hardware setup. Books like Gonzalez will be more relevant when you have images as pixels and process them to transform to more desirable images.

Here are the few tips:

1. Setup a hardware like [Raspberry PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) - a small general purpose computer
2. Add hardware I/O interface like [Camera Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module/)
3. You can use standard USB Dongles and make it work on your pi.
4. Write your application which will now collect pics and send across to the app on your smart phone!

Thats' it, really!